# Как по нажатию кнопки в python Открывалось приложение?

Tags: python, tkinter

Всем привет. Я новенький в python.
Я бы хотел узнать как сделать что бы в python открывалось приложение.
Например:
Появилось окно с кнопкой. Нажимаешь на кнопку и запустилось например - Steam, ну или другое приложение.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html

Со стимом просто, у него есть url обработчик

```
import os 
os.startfile(“steam://“)
```

Или для программ у которых известно место установки

```
 os.system(“c:/Program Files/The Program/programm.exe”)
```